# which one is better for developing an service app(Native or Hybrid)?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to know which one this items (Hybrid - Native) is better for developing an Service app like laundry or Carpet cleaning app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want fast development, less customization, synchronizer between Android and iOS, choose hybrid.
If you want best performance, deep customization, choose native